# How can I embed a Youtube video in a iOS6 app?

Tags: youtube-api

I have problems embedding Youtube videos in a iOS6 app.

The problem is that whenever I create a html element that uses the old / or new embed code, it opens Safari and shows the video

I use the Youtube API to get videos, and use PhoneGap

**Update**
The solution is to set OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES in Phonegap settings

Comment: It is fixed now, we had to set OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES in Phonegap settings

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIWebview` to load videos instead of Safari.

Here is a [sample code](http://www.developerfeed.com/ios/topic/how-embed-youtube-video-uiview-iphone)

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = rect.size;

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];
webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

NSString *videoUrl = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0";
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"320\" height=\"480\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\"></embed></object></div></body></html>",videoUrl,videoUrl]    ;


[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];

[window addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Comment: Your example shows a static embed. When creating video using the Youtube API it opens safari after creating them

Answer (score 0):

Not shure if you are talking a real APP (dont know anything about that)
but if its a WEBAPP (a normal webpage that tries to look as a real APP),
Then the only way i found to prevent youtube-videos from opening in Safari/Qt-player
is to embed it using "Fancybox" (maybe other boxes also).
that will keep it on the page in Youtube´s own player.

You can even have a original playlistplayer.
I stopped trying to embed youtube videos on iPhone-pages (to small)

I tried to include a link to a jSfiddle-example but this forum wont accept it
it forces me to write the whole example here...which i´m not going to do
because that is to much work for me right now.
(dont know how others are allowed to link to jSfiddle)
This forum is way to dictative to my taste.
Anyway you should be able to (incase of a webapp) find info at Fancybox´s website.

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried doing that using this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M78zz/) but it also opens Safari in iOS6

Comment: It worked for me,not shure if it helps you...but did you use what youtube calls the "new" embed-code (iframe/html5 method) replace the url in that jsFiddle for something like this                  <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLA4B53AFF1908367A&amp;autohide=1">PLAYLIST #1</a>

Comment: this forum really sucks on every post i make there´s new rules now i can not even edit after 5 minutes so i have to add a new comment  hope that works...its the last post i ever make on this dictator-forum try to replace the url for this  <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLA4B53AFF1908367A&amp;autohide=1">PLAYLIST #1</a>

Comment: All i have left is a url to a jsFiddle for a youtube-fancybox that worked on my iPhone4s ... this forum prevents me to send that...but it differs from your example only by that (above) url...i also used these tags:                                                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png"/>